# share data between events

Tags: node.js, race-condition

I tend to write a function like this:

```
library.getCookie(request.headers.cookie,function(cookies){
    db.query("SELECT name,lastupdate FROM session WHERE id=?",[cookies.SESSID],function(result){
        var action = require('./action');
        new action({
            data : result, 
            callback : function(){ // this callback's gonna run at the end of the request, after severals other db queries.
                require('fs').rename('/session/'+cookies.SESSID,'/session/'+require('crypto').randomBytes(20));
            }
        }).build();
    });   
});
```

I got a feeling that my `cookies.SESSID` is vunerable to race condition because it will be shared between severals IO events. If my concern is feasible, how can I fix my code?

Comment: Why change `cookies.SESSID`, normally session ids are only changed on create/login/logout? Also this is part of dealing with web development. You're using an asynchronous framework, HTTP, and then use a "synchronous" session. So it has some angles.

Comment: How is it subject to a race condition? Each time the callback is run, it gets its own local scope.

Comment: Additionally, it's less efficient to `require('./action')` every time than to just do it once at the beginning.

Comment: @EWit Actually, my session is expired in 30 minutes to prevent session fixation attack.

Comment: @Scimonster Could you explain more about this? I feel so confused with race-condition all the time.

Comment: @user3925697 Isn't it enough to renew the session on IP change, login, and logout  to prevent fixation attacks? Why bother changing it every 30 minutes .

Comment: @EWit Some users may keep logging in for days. And in this case, regenerating session id on login, logout and IP change is not enough. BTW, I think our discussion is off-topic.

Comment: Each time the function is run, it should be provided with its own local `cookies` variable. I don't see the issue of a race condition.

Comment: @Scimonster What happens if the `database query` is slow, then another request is coming that overwrites `cookies.SESSID` with a new one?

Comment: It cannot happen like that. Each time the function is run, it has its own copy of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables you want to pass to the more inner callback with `var` and you will stay safe. Otherwise you are just declaring them as implict global variables and each call of the function will overwrite the value you are expecting to get in the callback;

(the callback inside `action` could take the value of `cookies` not like the one you passed when you called the first time but a new value if the function is invoked before the first callback is solved)

I have just answered a similar question, with examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229739/race-condition-and-common-mistakes